# Python compare contents of gz files

Tags: python, file, comparison, equality

I have to compare a couple of pairs of gz files in Python. Idea is to run :

```
f1 = os.popen('file1.gz').read()
f2 = os.popen('file2.gz').read()
print(f1 == f2)
```

But this seems slow, since the whole content should be read. Is there another efficient way to check for equality of gz files in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `filecmp` library.

```
import filecmp

print(filecmp.cmp('file1.gz', 'file2.gz'))
```

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/filecmp.html) is the documentation.